# What is the use of option -u in the Linux cat command?

Tags: linux, centos-6

In the man page of cat, -u means (ignored)

```
[raj@localhost zzz]$ cat file1 
hello world 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0
! @ # $ % ^ & * ( ) _ + ~ ` ; ' , .{ } [ ] = | \ / -



[raj@localhost zzz]$ cat -u file1
hello world 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0
! @ # $ % ^ & * ( ) _ + ~ ` ; ' , .{ } [ ] = | \ / -
```

When should we use the -u option?

And what it will ignore?

Answer (score 6):

The option `-u` is so that `cat` and hence Unix/Linux is POSIX compliant. The [specification](http://www.unix.com/man-page/posix/1posix/cat/) says:

```
The following option shall be supported:

   -u     Write bytes from the input file to the standard output without delay as each is read.
```

In practice, `cat` does this automatically and there's no way to turn it off so the option is accepted but ignored as it has no effect on the behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

The option itself is being ignored. It probably existed in older or different versions of `cat`, so it does not end in an error if an older script uses it, but it does not change cat's behaviour in any way.